# How do I use the user roles from the Azure App Service Authentication feature in my .NET web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) to set up Authentication and Authorization in my .NET web app. I deployed the app to App Services and added authentication using Microsoft as the provider. All unauthenticated requests are redirected to log in, and only accounts in my Azure Active Directory are allowed to access the page. I set up two roles for the app in the App Registration screen, one called `Admin` and one called `User`. I added two users to my directory with a different role for this application.

If I leave my Program.cs as is, `HttpContext.User` has no claims and no identities in my controller. I can add this to `Program.cs` to get claims and identities:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

My controller methods look like this:

```cs
public IActionResult Index() {
  return Ok(new {
    Roles = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "roles")?.Value,
    HasUserRole = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("User"),
    HasAdminRole = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"),
    UserIsAuthenticated = HttpContext.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated,
    UserAuthType = HttpContext.User.Identity?.AuthenticationType,
  });
}
```

An authenticated response looks like this:

```js
{
  "roles": "User",
  "hasUserRole": false,
  "hasAdminRole": false,
  "userIsAuthenticated": true,
  "userAuthType": "aad"
}
```

The roles claim is there in the user object of HttpContext, but calling `IsInRole("User")` does not provide the expected response. Endpoints tagged with `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` will return a 403 error. Endpoints tagged with `[Authorize]` will work fine though.

I keep running into sample code provided by Microsoft that looks like [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/Startup.cs). The sample is using Bearer JWT authentication with the provider being OpenIdConnect. When I tried using examples like that, I either didn't see any change or my user claims were not loaded at all.

Comment: Did you create 2 App Roles or did you create 2 Scopes?

Comment: @SelmirAljic I created app roles (under AD > App Registrations > [app name] > App Roles), then added users to the app with assigned roles (under AD > Enterprise Applications > [app name] > Users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use user roles from the Azure App Service Authentication feature in .NET web app, you need to configure your app to use the Authorization policy to check the roles claim from the user's identity.

In the `Startup.cs` file, configure the authentication and authorization services to use `Microsoft Identity Web`.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", "User"));
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", "Admin"));
});
```

Added two policies `User` and `Admin` that require the `roles` claim to be present and contain the respective roles.

Add annotation or decorate your controller or action methods with the `[Authorize]` attribute to enforce authorization checks.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public IActionResult UserAction()
{
    return Ok();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult AdminAction()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Decorate the UserAction method with `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` attribute and AdminAction method with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute.

This means that the `UserAction` method can only be accessed by users who have the `User` role, and the `AdminAction` method can only be accessed by users who have the `Admin` role.

> You need to ensure that the user is authenticated before accessing the roles claim. The [Authorize] attribute checks for authentication by default, so you don't need to explicitly check for authentication in your controller methods.

Now, you should be able to use the user roles from the Azure App Service Authentication feature in your .NET web app.

Thanks to `jsanders` for the blog -[Azure App Service Authentication – App Roles](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-app-service-authentication-8211-app-roles/ba-p/392361).

Comment: `AddAzureAD` is obsolete and it didn't properly set up the roles either. I looked at the blog post you linked and he implements custom middleware the just adds the roles as the right role type and that works. Thanks for the answer!